# Next js, Lottie Cannot add property completed, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, lottie

I have a problem with Lottie's animation.
I fetch a JSON file (Lottie Animation) from Contentful, and I want to display it by Lottie Component.
But I receive an error: "TypeError: Cannot add property completed, the object is not extensible".

I don't know why I receive this error because, when I add a local JSON file from /public to property 'animationData', all works fine.

I tried everything. But local files always work well but json from cms does not.
Contentful also returned proper data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it would have been better if you posted you code ss here but nevertheless i can still guess it :D, i have worked previously with lottie on react apps, so,

1. have you downloaded from lottiefiles because you have written "from contentful", i dont know what is that but as long as you are using the predefined method it comes along with to run a JSON lottie it should be working fine.
2. "when I add a local JSON file from /public to property 'animationData', all works fine." , try tinkering with the method's attributes, see if it comes.

   // const defaultOptions = {
   //     loop: true,
   //     autoplay: true,
   //     animationData: breakingnews,
   //     rendererSettings: {
   //       preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
   //     }
   //   };

this was a piece i used in mine,

if this doesn't answer your question experiment on it, i'm sure will find something. happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error previously when it was imported in that manner:

```
import * as animationData from './anim.json';
```

Replace by:

```
import animationData from './anim.json';
```